# How can I download several files from the iInternet and wait for everyone to download?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, download

I need to download several HTML files in my ASP.NET application. The average file size is about 100 KB.

Right now I'm using the following code.

```
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        string url = (string)item.Element("link");
        string title = (string)item.Element("title");
        string fileName = Server.MapPath(title + ".html");

        // Add the attachement
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((a, b) =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName));
            counter++;

            // If we've downloaded all the items, send the message with the items attached to it
            if (counter == totalItems)
            {
                SendMessage(message);
            }
        });
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), fileName); 
    }
```

As you can see I'm downloading the files asynchronously, but the foreach loop doesn't care that the file hasn't been downloaded yet, it goes to the next iterated item.

As a result of this, some of the files are not downloaded.

Comment: Are you wanting to put a limit on how many you can concurrently download or do you want to download the files one at a time?

Comment: How/where are items, totalitems and counter set?

Comment: jp2code, I want to download files one at a time. totalItems = items.Count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET Framework 4 you could use Task class and [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to download all files in order using the WaitAll method.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CountdownEvent Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) to count down the number of remaining files.

```
var cde = new CountdownEvent(items.Count);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...

    client.DownloadFileCompleted += (a, b) =>
    {
        lock (message)
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName));
            cde.AddCount();
        }
    };

    ...
}

// If we've downloaded all the items,
// send the message with the items attached to it
cde.Wait();
lock (message)
{
    SendMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but unfortunately it didn't work... No files were downloaded at all. Where should I put the DownloadFileAsync call? After the event handler declaration?

Comment: I debugged the application, and the message.Attachments.Add part is not called at all

Answer (score 0):

It could as simple as a bug in your code to populate `totalItems`.

Try `if (counter == items.Count())`
instead of
`if (counter == totalItems)`

Comment: That's exactly what totalItems is :)